# How to find the value of the above limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the value of $$\lim:\lim_{x\to \infty} [(4/3)^{1/x}-(7/4)^{1/x}+(9/7)^{1/x}]^{x}$$ ? As far as I have guessed this limit is of the form of 1^{$\infty$}. So, now there exists a method for solving limits of the form of 1^{$\infty$}. For e.g.-If L=$$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0} [f(x)^{g(x)}]$$; where $$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0}[f(x)]$$=1 and $$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0}[g(x)]$$=$\infty$ then L=e^{$$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)×[f(x)-1]$$}×$$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0}[f(x)]$$. In this way only I am trying to solve this question but can't find any result. Please help me out with this question.

Comment: **Hint** Make $x=\frac 1 y$, take logarithms and use series

Comment: Can u show me the full calculation @ClaudeLeibovici. It will help me very much.

Answer (score 1):

lim : lim x→∞$[(4/3)^{1/x}−(7/4)^{1/x}+(9/7)^{1/x}]^x$

After using the formula you mentioned above, we get:

lim x→∞$e^{[x((4/3)^{1/x}−(7/4)^{1/x}+(9/7)^{1/x} -1)]}$
Then using expansion : $a^x = 1+x*ln(a)/1! + (x*ln(a))^2/2!....∞ $
we get,
lim x→∞ $e^{[x(1+ln(4/3)/x−1-ln(7/4)/x+1+ ln(9/7)/x -1)]}$

lim x→∞ $e^{[x(ln(4/3)/x-ln(7/4)/x+ln(9/7)/x)]}$

lim x→∞ ${e^[ln(4/3)-ln(7/4)+ln(9/7)]}$

$e^{[ln(16/21)+ln(9/7)]}$

$e^{ln(48/49)}$

=48/49

This should be the final answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Rhythmic_ Ocean

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> I see you want us to use a specific method and it already has been answered. So I will suggest an alternative that will use L'Hoptial:

$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty}{\left((4/3)^{1/x} - (7/4)^{1/x} + (9/7)^{1/x}\right)}^x
\\\Rightarrow \ln{L} = \lim_{x \to \infty}{x\cdot\ln{\left((4/3)^{1/x} - (7/4)^{1/x} + (9/7)^{1/x}\right)}}
\\\iff\lim_{x \to \infty}{\dfrac{\ln{\left((4/3)^{1/x} - (7/4)^{1/x} + (9/7)^{1/x}\right)}}{1/x}}$$

By L'Hopital

$$\ln{L} = \lim_{x \to \infty}{\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln{\left((4/3)^{1/x} - (7/4)^{1/x} + (9/7)^{1/x}\right)}}{\dfrac{d}{dx}(1/x)}}
\\\quad
\\= \lim_{x \to \infty}{-\dfrac{\left(\ln{(3/4)}\cdot(4/3)^{1/x} + \ln{(7/4)}\cdot(7/4)^{1/x} + \ln{(7/9)}\cdot(9/7)^{1/x}\right)}{\left((4/3)^{1/x} - (7/4)^{1/x} + (9/7)^{1/x}\right)\cdot x^2}\cdot x^2}
\\\to-\dfrac{\left(\ln{(3/4)}\cdot1 + \ln{(7/4)}\cdot1 + \ln{(7/9)}\cdot1\right)}{\left(1 - 1 + 1\right)}
\\=-\ln{((3/4) \cdot (7/4) \cdot (9/7))}
\\= \ln{\dfrac{48}{49}}$$

Hence,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{L = e^{\ln{(48/49)}} = \dfrac{48}{49}}$$

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to\infty,$
$$\begin{align}\ln\left([(4/3)^{1/x}-(7/4)^{1/x}+(9/7)^{1/x}]^{x}\right)&=x\ln[e^{\frac1x\ln(4/3)}-e^{\frac1x\ln(7/4)}+e^{\frac1x\ln(9/7)}]\\
&=x\ln\left[1+\frac{\ln(4/3)-\ln(7/4)+\ln(9/7)}x+o(1/x)\right]\\&\to\ln(4/3)-\ln(7/4)+\ln(9/7)=\ln\frac{48}{49},
\end{align}$$

hence

$$[(4/3)^{1/x}-(7/4)^{1/x}+(9/7)^{1/x}]^x\to\frac{48}{49}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Making $y=1/x$ we have

$$
L=\lim_{y\to 0} [(4/3)^{y}-(7/4)^{y}+(9/7)^{y}]^{\frac 1y}
$$

and for small $y$ we have

$$
(4/3)^{y}-(7/4)^{y}+(9/7)^{y} = 1+y \left(\log \left(\frac{9}{7}\right)+\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\log \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\right)+O\left(y^2\right)=1-y \log \left(\frac{49}{48}\right)+O\left(y^2\right)
$$

then

$$
L = \lim_{y\to 0}\left(1-y \log \left(\frac{49}{48}\right)\right)^{\frac 1y} = \frac{48}{49}
$$